# Please help to understand the verb suffix 掛ける

Tags: verbs, suffixes

I have a sentence フライト・アテンダントはよく話しかけてくれて親しみがありました。
Where 話しかけて is what I can't understand. What sort of suffix is "shikakete"? Or is it two suffixes, shi + kakete?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference in terms of grammar between ～かける　and　～っぱなし?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5860/78).

Comment: Oh... but the かける in 食べかける/やりかける is different from the かける in 話しかける, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

話しかける or 話し掛ける means to address or speak to someone.

You can think of it as two suffixes shi + kakeru, but it looks more like two verbs to me. There are many verbs with かける (掛ける) attached. For example, 投げ掛ける meaning to "throw at" or 呼び掛ける meaning "to call out to".

With your example, the difference between 話して and 話し掛けて might be that the latter assumes that your not as close to the person as in the former.