# "開けっぱなし" What's the grammar of `っぱ`?

Tags: grammar

"開けっぱなし" What's the grammar of `っぱ`?

> 冷蔵庫を開けっぱなしにしていたから、中の物が悪くなってしまった。

Comment: If you've been failing to find it by searching it's because you need to look for ～っぱなし

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In kanji, it's 開けっ放し, not "開けっぱ + 無し". Here `っぱなし` is a kind of suffix that adds the nuance of "(do ～ and) leave it".

- [What is the difference in terms of grammar between ～かける　and　～っぱなし?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5860/5010)
- [っ放し in 実用日本語表現辞典](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A3%E6%94%BE%E3%81%97)

  > その動作が持続しているさま、その状態のまま放置されている様子などを意味する表現。行為の後、後始末をせずに置くという意味合いの強いことも多い。「扉を開けっ放しにする」「コンクリートの打ちっぱなし」「投げっぱなしジャーマンスープレックス」「打ちっぱなしゴルフ練習場」など。

That said, 開けっぱ is occasionally used slangily as an abbreviation of 開けっ放し.

- 窓が開けっ放しになっている。(standard)
  ≈ 窓が開けっぱになってる。(slang)
  The window is left open.

Answer (score 1):

blah**っぱなし** equals blah**っ放し**, which is also equal to blah**放し**.

開け**っぱなし** → 開け**っ放し** → 開け**放し**

So to answer your question

> What's the grammar of っぱ?

"〜っぱなし" is derived from "〜放し".

When saying the word out loud, definitely the っ kicks in. Literally pronouncing without the っ will sound weird and may lead to confusion.

Going the other direction, we may also say 開けっぱ, which is close to slang.

e.g. *冷蔵庫が開けっぱ*