# What is the meaning of 付きっきり?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the meaning of 付きっきり?

I usually see it used in the sense of "babysitting" is this the only meaning?

Comment: Here is a helpful post: [5855](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5855/)

Answer (score 3):

[Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A) defines it as "constant attendance; uninterrupted supervision; staying with someone all the time", while [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A):

> 少しも離れることなく付き添うこと。つきっきり

which I would translate as "To attend to someone without ever leaving", so it means to attend on someone costantly; "babysitting" fits in this, but given Weblio's example (付きっきりで看病する, "To nurse someone costantly") I'd say it has a broader meaning.

Answer (score 2):

つきっきり means "to be together all the time", "to stick with someone".